# Android Java Retrofit repeating call gives ConnectException

Tags: java, android, heroku, retrofit

Hello I want to call the request again and again once the call is done. I am doing it like this:

OnContinueUserPing.java

```
public interface OnContinueUserPing {

    void onContinue();
}
```

GameActivity.java

```
 public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnContinueUserPing {
    
    (...)

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            restModel.setUserPing(login, this);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onContinue() {
                restModel.setUserPing(login, this);
        }
    }
```

RestModel.java

```
public void setUserPing(String login, OnContinueUserPing onContinueUserPing) {
    Call<String> result = Api.getClient().setUserPing(login);
    result.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
            Log.e("setUserPingResponse", "a");
            onContinueUserPing.onContinue();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("setUserPingError", t.toString());
            call.clone().enqueue(this);
        }
    });
}
```

It works for about first few minutes. But then I get only: `java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to MY_URL`

I can add that I send those calls to my heroku app (free plan if this is important).

How can I solve those failed connections? Thank you in advance!

Comment: you do not make a request call again and again.

Comment: You are wrong. I see not ending logs from this call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloning the `call` object `onFailure` might pose some issues. Try changing,

```
call.clone().enqueue(this);
```

to

```
onContinueUserPing.onContinue();
```

---

Heroku might also reject continuous requests to the server. Try adding an additional parameter to the URL, and on each request change that parameter.

```
int requestCount = 1;
String url = "http://your.domain.url?reqCount=" + requestCount++;
```

---

Meanwhile, your approach is not a good practice. You should try polling in set intervals or use something like a WebSocket.

Comment: It does not solve the issue, stil receiving many ConnectErrors

Comment: @Kiubaz Is the server expecting a `GET` request? Does it work correctly for the first few minutes? Have you tested it locally?

Comment: Yes I have set @GetMapping for that URL.  It works correectly for a first minutes after a while the problem occurs. Hmmm.. are you sure heroku accepts this URL parameter reqcount? I could not find anything about it on their official website

Comment: @Kiubaz it doesn't matter whether heroku accepts the param, the intention is to change the request URL every time.

Comment: Still the same. But maybe something is wrong with my Okhttp client and I should change somehting in OkHttpClient.Builder()? Or another option can be maybe limits with my ISP provider?

Comment: I also noticed onFailure t.toString() shows url with strange IP and port attached to after / of by base url. I have not added that to base url, where is it comming from?

Comment: Add `.cache(null)` to the `OkHttpClient.Builder()`. Do you use [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) or any API testing tool? Or even from your browser, send multiple requests to the server and check what happens.

Comment: It depends what I type. If I type https://jawegiel-web.herokuapp.com/setUserPing?login=LOGIN&reqCount=REQ_COUNT then it always works but when I type the URL from error log for example jawegiel-web.herokuapp.com/18.208.60.216:443 then it never works just spinner spins around. Now is the question where does this IP and port come from? I did not add any IP in my baseUrl... This IP changes often in my error log.

Comment: OMG.. this .cache(null) gives no effect for me. Sorry for that it's not my fault :(

Comment: @Kiubaz `18.208.60.216` is the exact IP address for your URL, and the port `443` comes because you used `https`. OkHttp might just be adding it to the `Throwable` don't worry about it.

Comment: Ok, I see on mobile network there are no errors, but on my WIFI problem appears. How to solve that?

Comment: @Kiubaz in that case your router could be equipped with a firewall and most probably it is identifying this as a DOS attack. You'll have to manually disable it from the router's settings.

Comment: It could be this because when those errors appear WIFI stops working. When I close the app, internet starts working again, strange thing... So thank you anyway. Issue not solved yet, but I will mark ur answer as a best one for ur ur really valuable help, kind regards! ;)